# Git remove remote repositorie

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm having this problem.

I opened new folder named /folder and want to put my /app1 folder inside of it and push it on https://github.com/me/app1.git

So I opened new /folder and type `git init` to initialize it. After that i checked if I have any remotes, `git remote -v` and got

> origin https://git.someserver.com/app0.git (fetch)
>
> origin https://git.someserver.com/app0.git (push)

This is remote which I used on my last project. And in my config file, there is no url defined.

I tried with `git remote set-url https://github.com/me/app1.git`, but the result was all three of these remotes:

> origin https://git.someserver.com/app0.git (fetch)
>
> origin https://git.someserver.com/app0.git (push)
>
> origin http://github.com/me/app1.git (push)

Now i have url: http://github.com/me/app1.git defined in my config file.

Further I tried to `git remote rm origin`, hoped to remove all origins but I just removed the added app1.git one.

So, how to remove these "old" remotes, I don't want to remove this app0.git repo from someserver.com, I just want to remove its connection to my newly created local /folder.

Tnx

Comment: Did you try running `git remote rm origin` multiple times?

Comment: just tried and error: Could not remove config section "remote.origin"